# How to cluster two datasets into a single heatmap using two separate scales in Python?

Tags: python, matplotlib, heatmap, seaborn, hierarchical-clustering

I am trying to perform clustering analysis on two datasets using the
[cluster heatmap function in Seaborn.](http://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.clustermap.html)

The problem is that the two datasets come from two different procedures and thus they contain values that are differently distributed (I mean, the 1st dataset has a scale of values ranging from 0 to 1, but the 2nd from 1000 up to 5000).

**My question is:**

How can I cluster two datasets that have different range of values? Is there a way to cluster the rows of the datasets into a single heatmap and maybe have two scales for each dataset?

Here what I have tried so far, but with only little success:

```
#First, I have combined the two datasets into one dataframe object:
dataset = pd.concat([dataset_1, dataset_2], axis=0)

#Then, passed the dataframe into Seaborn's `.clustermap()` function:
sns.clustermap(data=dataset, 
    col_cluster=False)
```

**Output:** you can notice that the features of `dataset_1` are all blocked out because of the scale of the difference in scale between the datasets (`dataset_1` and `dataset_2` as shown bellow)

[image]

Any idea how to approach this problem?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

You could use sklearn's preprocessing library, specifically the scaler before creating the clustermap.

The documentation is here: http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.preprocessing.scale.html#sklearn.preprocessing.scale

Comment: Standardizing the data seems to be not quite helpful in this case.  I mean no meaningful patterns could be attained from the cluster heatmap visually.  I think this could be the case because the variance of `dataset_2` is much larger than the variance of `dataset_1`. And this might cause the estimator to be inaccurate.  I read that from [sklearn.preprocessing.StandardScaler source][https://github.com/scikit-learn/scikit-learn/blob/a24c8b46/sklearn/preprocessing/data.py#L478]

Comment: I tried scaling the dataset by rows.  Do you mean to scale `dataset_2` feature alone to so its scale becomes relatively matching with the scale of values in`dataset_1`? Thanks

Comment: Yes, that was what I meant